# How can I use Python namedtuples to insert rows into mySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, namedtuple

I have used namedtuples to read rows from mySQL ... it is great. Can I use the same mechanism to INSERT rows into mySQL.
My system is changing quite a bit, so I need an simple way to map python values to columns in the database, without having to check the order of the values/columns every time I change my program
I am using mySQLDB library - but could change

Answer (score 3):

namedtuple for INSERT queries will behave just like normal tuples, you have to maintain the order of column/values. You can use named placeholders and dicts to avoid that.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES (%(name)s, %(age)s)", {"name": "Bernard", "age": 30})
```

Related question: [Python MySQLdb: Query parameters as a named dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831408/python-mysqldb-query-parameters-as-a-named-dictionary)