# Python mysql using variable to select a certain field

Tags: python, mysql, select, field

Having a little tricky issue with python and mysql. To keep it simple, the following code returns whatever is in the variable 'field', which is a string. Such as 'username' or 'password'.

```
options = [field, userID]
entries = cursor.execute('select (?) from users where id=(?)', options).fetchall()
print(entries);
```

This code works correctly if I remove the first (?) and just use the actually name (like 'username') instead. Can anyone provide some input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is actually formed as:

```
select "field" from users where id="value"
```

which returns you a string "field" instead of the actual table field value.

*You cannot parameterize column and table names* ([docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)):

> Parameter placeholders can only be used to insert column values. They
>   can not be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names,
>   statements, etc.

Use string formatting for that part:

```
options = [userID]
query = 'select {field} from users where id=(?)'.format(field=field)
cursor.execute(query, options).fetchall()
```

Related threads with some more explanations:

- [pysqlite: Placeholder substitution for column or table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841488/pysqlite-placeholder-substitution-for-column-or-table-names)
- [Python MySQLdb: Query parameters as a named dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831408/python-mysqldb-query-parameters-as-a-named-dictionary)

Comment: How about safety?

Comment: @NikolayShindarov in that case, the responsibility of additional pre-validating/escaping is on the author of the code.