# How to update MySQL cell with variable in MySQLDB

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
import serial
import MySQLdb

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root”,”test”,”ISEF_DB") or die ("Could not connect to database")
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyACM0'

try:
    print "Trying...",device
    arduino = serial.Serial(device, 250000)
except:
    print "Failed to connect on",device

try:
    data = arduino.readline() #read data
#   pieces = data.split("\t")
    print "The data is:",data

    try:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = 'data'")
        dbConn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        print "data inserted"
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "Failed to insert data"
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        print "done"
except:
    print "Failed to get data"
```

When I execute this code, it seems like it is working, though it does not update the **present** cell to **1**. If I change `'data'` to any known cell id, **present** is updated to **1**. So, how do I update a cell from a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '{}'".format(data))
```

This "inserts" the value of `data` into your SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

You must use string formatting to substitute variable for its value

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '%s'" % data)
```

Although be warned that this leaves you susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). To prevent that you can use exceute like so ([from the docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples))

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '%s'", (data,))
```

i.e. pass the values as tuples to `execute`. More information about avoiding SQL injection when using MySQLDB can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929364/python-best-practice-and-securest-to-connect-to-mysql-and-execute-queries)

Comment: Those are both executing without error, however they still aren't updating the data in the database. Do the datatypes need to be something else? They currently are `CHAR(8)` for the id column and `INT(11)` for the present column. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure ``data`` variable holds correct ID value? Maybe it has extra characters like ``\n`` or spaces?