# What is the correct way to use .format when passing other variables in the select query for MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

What is the correct way to use .format when I want to pass other variables in the select query for MySQL?

For example I have this query that I can't figure out how to pass all the parameters together correctly

```
a = "c9" # this is for %s
b = "TEMP" # this is for the first {}
c = "1 hour" # this is for the last {}
c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, Date_Time from data where Client = %s and Date_Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {}".format(b,a,c)) # This doesn't work
```

I also tried many other variations but they didn't work as well, I am still getting the `1064` error. So, what's the correct way?!

Comment: What's the 1064 error?

Comment: Have you tried to change %s to {}

Comment: @RushyPanchal http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: You miss a right parentheses `)`. It should be `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {}` **)**. Pls refer to my answer for the detailed description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case,

- miss a right parenthesis `)`;
- mix up the usage in [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) and [`format % values`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Try this:

```
>>> a = "c9" # this is for %s
>>> b = "TEMP" # this is for the first {}
>>> c = "1 hour" # this is for the last {}
>>> sql = "SELECT Client, {}, Date_Time from data where Client = \"{}\" and Date_Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {})".format(b,a,c)
>>> sql
'SELECT Client, TEMP, Date_Time from data where Client = "c9" and Date_Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 hour)'
>>>
>>> cur = db.cursor()
>>> cur.execute(sql)  
>>> data = cur.fetchall()   
>>> cur.close()
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This worked like a boss. Why did we need the `\"{}\"` for the second variable tho?

Comment: `Client = {}` will be `Client=c9`. I suppose `c9` should be a string. But wait, you miss a `=`?  `Client == "C9"`?

Comment: Oh now I get it. No no the query only needs on `=` so `Client = \"{}\"` is actually correct

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a single formatting system - `{}` is a [newer style formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) whereas `%s` is older.

Change this

```
c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, Date_Time from data where Client = %s and Date_Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {}".format(b,a,c)) # This doesn't work
```

to

```
c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, Date_Time from data where Client = {} and Date_Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {}".format(b,a,c))
```

You can also used named fields:

```
c.execute("SELECT Client, {field}, Date_Time from data where Client = {client} and Date_Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {interval}".format(
    field = b, client = a, interval = c))
```

However, it's not always the best idea to use string interpolation (i.e formatting) in queries, because of SQL injection attacks and other exploits that can occur. You need to sanitize the user data before passing it into the query – libraries conforming to the DB API should do this for you. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929438/1730261) for a more concrete example.

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried your answer first but I had error 1054: `Unknown column 'c9' in 'where clause'`. The other one worked for me.