# Preventing sql injections mysqldb python3.6

Tags: python, mysql

This is my script using MySQLdb with python3.6

```
import MySQLdb

# start connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "asdf", "projecten")

# create cursor
c = db.cursor()

# insert multiple records using a tuple
cities = [
    ('Boston', 'MA', 600000),
    ('Chicago', 'IL', 2700000),
    ('Houston', 'TX', 2100000),
    ('Phoenix', 'AZ', 1500000)
]

# sql statement
sql = "INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"

# insert data into table with list cities
c.executemany(sql, cities)

# commit changes
db.commit()

# close connection
db.close()
```

Is this safe against sql injections because some people use ? instead of %s but on python3.6 that is not working

Comment: What exactly is your question? because you are using %s and not ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Bruno says in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929438) to a related question:

> To avoid injections, use `execute` with `%s` in place of each variable, then pass the value via a list or tuple as the second parameter of `execute`.

Following this advice, you can create your SQL like this:

```
sql ="""INSERT INTO projecten.population (city, state, population)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""

c.executemany(sql, cities)
```

This is a much safer approach than what you have now.

Comment: So my script is safe

Comment: Not entirely. I have updated my reply. Check again

Comment: Isn't that the same that I already have in my code

Comment: I am using 3 double quotes. 3 Double quotes allow us to specify strings which spawn over multiple lines and contain special characters without the need to escape them. Basically anything between a pair of them is considered a string. These come in very handy when dealing with large inputs and also invoking commands over sql/ssh via python etc..