# How do I add a variable to a sql query?

Tags: python, mysql

I am getting the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near %s
How do I add a variable to my sql query?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="",
    password="",
    database="seahub_db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
ip = "Myip"
sql = "UPDATE constance_config SET value = %s WHERE id=1"
mycursor.execute(sql, ip)

mydb.commit()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: Please read about SQL Injections and see if you feel your code is secure.

Comment: @dfundako Where do you see a possibility for injection? This is a parameterized query, no string interpolation in Python is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of '.format()' vs. '%s' in cursor.execute() for mysql JSON field, with Python mysql.connector,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653106/use-of-format-vs-s-in-cursor-execute-for-mysql-json-field-with-pytho)

Answer (score 1):

The cursor's `execute()` function expects a tuple as the second parameter:

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)
ip = ("Myip",)
sql = "UPDATE constance_config SET value = %s WHERE id=1"
mycursor.execute(sql, ip)
```

Note also that I open the cursor in prepared statement mode.  You might not need to do this explicitly, but I am doing it for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: How does that explain the SQL syntax error though?

Comment: @Thomas If Python passes a malformed prepared statement, what would make you think that it might not result in a MySQL syntax error on the database side?

Comment: Of course, but I don't see a malformed prepared statement here. The `UPDATE` statement seems valid to me, yet MySQL raises a _syntax error_, not something like "expected tuple but got string". Or am I missing something?

Comment: We don't know what Python ends up passing to MySQL if we don't use a tuple to store the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

```
ip = "Myip"
sql = "UPDATE constance_config SET value = '" + ip + "' WHERE id=1"
```

It is important not to forget the quotes in the "sql" character string so that your variable is indeed a string in your sql request

Comment: Your answer is _wide open_ for SQL injection and should never be used in production.  Read about how to use prepared statements to avoid this pattern.