# clientlibrary.paramstyle is not working like it should

Tags: python, mysql

There is a question called : [Python best practice and securest to connect to MySQL and execute queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929842/9733868) an there Mr. Kirk Strauser says:

> You can see which your client library supports by looking at the
>   paramstyle module-level variable:

```
>>> clientlibrary.paramstyle
'pyformat'
```

But when I run this on my python 3 I get :

```
>>> clientlibrary.paramstyle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'clientlibrary' is not defined
```

I also searched in pip

```
pip3 search clientlibrary
<nothing>
```

what can I do ?

Comment: OK, you are hiding, ... I can see you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paramstyle is required for any python database module (see [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), the clientlibrary is just a placeholder for the datbase module you're using.

E.g.

```
>>> import mysql.connector as clientlibrary
>>> clientlibrary.paramstyle
'pyformat
>>> import mariadb as clientlibrary
>>> clientlibrary.paramstyle
'qmark
```

Comment: when I try to do this I got : `>>> import mariadb as clientlibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mariadb' `

Comment: but it worked with `import mysql.connector as clientlibrary`

Comment: Since you didn't install the database modules. Maybe mariadb is not a good example, since it's not available yet via PyPi and still alpha. But these modules were already installed on my machine.