# Cant use dash(-) in value in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I ave been trying to insert data to MYSQL table from python. The fields in my sql table are id, token, start_time, end_time, and no_of_trans.
I want to store a token generated using `uuid4` in the token column. But since the value contains `(-)`, I'm getting this error:
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '3900af75' in 'field list''`
where the token generated is: `3900af75-4563-4c05-81ba-b0f1630abecc`

And also I've tried inserting date in string format that also doesn't work. So I explicitly passed the date value as a string:
`mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO generate (token, start_time, end_time, no_of_trans) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""" %(rand_token, '2020-04-20', '2020-04-20', 3))`

Which inserts data into table but date is treated as a integer and the value that gets stored is `1996` which is nothing but `2020-04` from the date I've passed.

Here's the screenshot of my table:
[image]

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| token       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_time    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| no_of_trans | int(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: String literals must be enclosed with single quote chars `'`.

Comment: And what is *INSERT INTO generate (**`12`**, start_time, end_time ...* ?

Comment: @Akina I think the problem here is the Python UUID.  I'm not sure the statement API is smart enough to figure out how to bind it.

Comment: @Akina, can you please be more specific?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen UUID transfer is specified as string `%s` - I doubt it is a problem to convert UUID to string for python...

Comment: If the problem is with UUID at least other fields should work when I'm explicitly passing the value in place of UUID. But, instead the dates with '```-'``` are still not working.

Comment: I think the syntax you're looking for is `mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO generate (token, start_time, end_time, no_of_trans) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (rand_token, '2020-04-20', '2020-04-20', 3))` note `,`, not `%`

Comment: See comment posted by @Nick. If you are going to do string formatting using the `%` operator as you are currently doing, then you need to enclose each `%s` that corresponds to a string value with quotes, i.e. `VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %s)`. But the prepared statement, which prevents SQL Injection attacks when the input is "from the outside", is the way to go.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929364/python-best-practice-and-securest-to-connect-to-mysql-and-execute-queries That is a question about SQL injection, but the answers are the clearest explanation of the solution you are looking for that I have seen.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, your solution worked for me!!

Comment: @VishalA. no worries - I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

All but the last %s in your VALUES part need to be enclosed in single quotes as you are passing character strings. e.g. Without quotes 2020-04-20 becomes 1996.

But the actual problem seems to be to be the first unquoted %s, so that your rand_token variable value is interpreted as

3900af75 - 4563 - 4c05 - 81ba - b0f1630abecc

So "value of column 3900af75 minus literal number 4563 minus column with name 4c05 ..."