# Python : Safe way to insert multiple values to psql table

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, sql-injection, psql

So to insert multiple values to my psql table I use the following code:

```
sql_query = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s)" % (table_name, my_columns)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(sql_query, tupled_data)
```

where `tupled_data` is a list of tuples where each element in each tuple is a new entry for the corresponding column. 
I want to know if this is a safe way to do this kind of stuff ? Is it secured from sql injections ? 
I found some possible answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929364/python-best-practice-and-securest-way-to-connect-to-mysql-and-execute-queries) but it only states that it is safe for the `cursor.execute()` function and I want to know if it is the same for `executemany()`

Comment: If the table and column names are from untrusted input then you are not safe.  Psycopg2 provides tools for constructing SQL queries safely, you can use those.

Comment: @snakecharmerb only the data provided as tupled_data is from the user